# can we use extends: and script: | together in azure pipeline yaml file

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to extend a template in azure pipeline yaml file where I face unexpected value issue, cant we use script: inside extends?

```
resources:
 repositories:
  - repository: templates
    name: repo/templates
    ref: "develop"
    type: git

  
# First CI Run test
extends:
  template: governed-template/build.yml@templates 
  script: |
    mkdir -p $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/binarydownloads
  displayName: Validate Pipeline Artifacts
  
  parameters:
    releaseId: ${{ parameters.releaseId }}
```

Throws unexpected value error at the script line, please help.

Iam trying to write CICD pipeline in Azure and facing the above issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported in Azure YAML pipelines.

The **`extends`** key cannot be used together with the keys **`stages`**, **`stage`**, **`jobs`**, **`job`**, **`steps`**, **`task`**, **`script`** and the child keys related them.

Comment: `resources:
 repositories:
  - repository: templates
    name: repo/templates
    ref: "develop"
    type: git

  script: |
    mkdir -p $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/binarydownloads
  displayName: Validate Pipeline Artifacts
# First CI Run test
extends:
  template: governed-template/build.yml@templates 
    
  parameters:
    releaseId: ${{ parameters.releaseId }}` is this also not supported?

Comment: script on top of extends also not supported?

Comment: @AiswaryaM, It also is not available.